# How to select all items which the user didn't vote for yet (vote system)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

```
videos: id, name, path...
users: id, name,...
likes: id, user_id, video_id,...
```

I want to select all videos where my user didn't vote.

I've tried:

```
SELECT `videos`.* 
FROM `videos` 
WHERE `id` NOT IN (
   SELECT `video_id` FROM `likes` WHERE likes.`user_id` IS NOT '1'
) 
ORDER BY RAND() ASC 
LIMIT 10
```

I also should mention that my user only can see 10 items at once, randomly chosen, thats why i ordered them randomly and limited this by 10.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you comment on how the SQL you have tried does not meet your requirements?

Comment: `Can someone help me?` Maybe. Maybe not. -- *Was that your question?*

Comment: Sequel Pro gives me this error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''1')
ORDER BY RAND() ASC 
LIMIT 10' at line 1" @brianchandley

Comment: you look for the videos that are not voted by a specific user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this which uses `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT  videos.*
FROM    videos
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  1
        FROM    likes
        WHERE   likes.id = videos.id
        AND     likes.user_id = USER_ID
        )
```

Comment: You man, are a hero! It works like a charm! Please upvote this everybody! I can't :)